# Explicit loading in EF Core randomly loads .Include()

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have .NET 5 project with `Index` page where is table containing all rows from table `Contracts`, each row has `Contract_StatusID` column where is saved FK from table `Contract_Statuses` - table `Contracts` has more columns with this logic

Thing is, that Explicit loading is loading fully only last row of the table, other row's columns are randomly `null`, even when collection is `.Include(s => s.Contract_Status)` from controller code.
All ID columns are set, and these IDs are existing in related tables, but not loaded into this table on Index page.

`Detail` page always correctly load all `.Include()` relation tables but not on `Index` page.

I've validated my models and they looks OK, and work within other pages of the site.

What I am missing? Already went through MSDN and EFCore tutorials for this, but it just don't work.

[image]

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var contract = await context.Contracts
        .Include(c => c.Employee)
            .ThenInclude(c => c.Gender)
        .Include(i => i.Business_Unit)
        .Include(i => i.Brand)
        .Include(i => i.Contract_Status)
        .Include(i => i.Statutory_Unit)
        .Include(i => i.Management_Market).ToListAsync();
    return View(contract);
}
```

Edit: Adding my `Index.cshtml`

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Contract>    
<table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Employee)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contract_Status.Contract_Status)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Business_Unit.Business_Unit)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Brand.Brand)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Statutory_Unit.Statutory_Unit)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Management_Market.Management_Market)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Employee.EmployeeID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contract_Status.Contract_Status)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Business_Unit.Business_Unit)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Brand.Brand)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Statutory_Unit.Statutory_Unit)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Management_Market.Management_Market)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ContractID">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ContractID">Details</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And my `Contract` model with example of related table

```
    public class Contract
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public Guid ContractID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public Employee Employee { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Contract_StatusID { get; set; }
        public CONF_Contract_Status Contract_Status { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Business_UnitID { get; set; }
        public CONF_Business_Unit Business_Unit { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int BrandID { get; set; }
        public CONF_Brand Brand { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Statutory_UnitID { get; set; }
        public CONF_Statutory_Unit Statutory_Unit { get; set; }


        [Required]
        public int Management_MarketID { get; set; }
        public CONF_Management_Market Management_Market { get; set; }
    }

public class CONF_Contract_Status
{
    [Key]
    public int CS_ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public string Contract_Status { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public Contract Contract { get; set; }
}
```

DB screenshot of `Contract` table
[image]

and `CONF_Contract_Status`

[image]

Comment: can you show your index view, pls?

Comment: I've edited my question with these details.

Comment: Your employee class looks strange. Can you post the real code pls?

Comment: Sorry, I've noticed it immediately, unfortunately, there are some business specific things, which I am not allowed to share, so I was re-writing it to this example. Otherwise real-world code is for relationship between Contract and Contract Statuses, and other properties of contract. The thing is, everything is set, when I am using same query on Detail page, it works just fine I get all related tables with correct values

Comment: You have to post more info  and real code if you really need some help . I can only see the black boxes and code that can be evern compiled. I understand the data can have some private information, what private information can have standard very simple code that can be found in any textbook

Comment: My approach to solve those problems is to check the code first, then check the database for the first item that looks wrong and then go back to the code. This is impossible without having real data and real code.

Comment: added real code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually alway create view model for index view, since it is usually needed several string columns, but it can have a lot of columsn. YOu don't need to bring from the server the whole record if you only need one column

```
 public class ContractVieModel
    {
        public Guid ContractID { get; set; }

        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public  string Contract_Status { get; set; }
        public string Business_Unit { get; set; }
        
      .... and so on
    }
```

action, you don't to use Include  explicetly

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var model = await context.Contracts
    .Select(i=> new ContractViewModel
     {
       Id=i.Id,
       EmployeeName=i.Employee.Name
      Contract_Status =i.Contract_Status.Contract_Status,
      Business_Unit = i.Business_Unit.Business_Unit,
      ... and so on 
      }).ToListAsync();

    return View(model);
}
```

view

```
@model IEnumerable<ContractViewModel> 

......
```

try it , and if it is still not working then you will have to use left outer joins to get a view model

Comment: Thank you, so I've just changed my Includes to 
 var contract = await _HRConsoleDbContext.Contracts
                .Select(i => new Contract
                {
                    Employee = i.Employee,
                    Contract_Status = i.Contract_Status,
                    Business_Unit = i.Business_Unit,
                    Brand = i.Brand,
                    Statutory_Unit = i.Statutory_Unit,
                    Management_Market = i.Management_Market
                }).ToListAsync();

Sorry, for my original post. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are very welcome!